# Imploding $_POST variable

Tags: php, arrays, string

i have this code that saves values from $POST , but one variable [segments] needs to be imploded but i dont know how to achieve that
My code:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
        
      
     

        if (!$id = $request->id) $this->_redirect('/' . $this->_name);
        $guest = ($guestTable = new Table_Guests())->fetchRow(
            $guestTable
            ->select()
            ->where('id_objects = ?', $this->getObjectId())
            ->where('id = ?', $id)
        );
        $this->view->form = $guest->form();

        if ($request->isPost() && $this->view->form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
           //
            implode($_POST['segments']);
            $post = $_POST;
            unset($post['saveBtn']);

           
            
            
    
            
            try {
                foreach ($post as $key => $value) $guest->$key = $value;
                
                $guest->save();
                $this->_helper->flashMessenger(array('info' => $this->view->translate('The changes have been saved')));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_helper->flashMessenger(array('error' => $this->view->translate('Cannot save changes')));
            }
            
          
            $this->_redirect('/' . $this->_name);
        }
        
        $this->view->title = $this->view->translate('Guests') . ' <span>/ ' . $this->view->translate('Edit') . '</span>';
```

Short version of the output :

```
array (size=27)
  'first_name' => string 'Test' (length=4)
  'segments' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'uno' (length=3)
      1 => string 'dos' (length=3)
      2 => string 'tres' (length=4)
  'birthday' => string '0000-00-00' (length=10)
```

And one desired thing that needs to be is

```
'segments'=> string(uno,dos,tres)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You forgot to assign the return value of `implode` to anything (possibly back to the post field)

Comment: `$_POST['segments'] = implode(',', $_POST['segments'])`. You need to save the response of the call somewhere. You also need to define the separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was adding

```
$_POST['segments'] = implode(',', $_POST['segments'])
```